# How to crack a password created using a keypad with keys 0 through 9

Tags: probability

I'm thinking about getting a Encrypted Hardrive. You have a keypad with the numerals $0$ through $9$ that you can use for your $8$ digit password. How many different $8$ digit combinations are possible using numbers $0$ through $9$?

Comment: I suggest you edit the title so that it pertains to the math question. e.g., "How many different 8 digit combinations are possible using numbers 0 through 9?"

Answer (score 1):

Your first digit could be any of 10, so a 1-digit combination would have 10 possibilities.

Each of those 10 could be followed by another 10 for a 2-digit combination, leading to $10^2$ or 100 combinations.

You are looking at an 8-digit combination. That would lead to $10^8$, or 100,000,000 possible combinations.

The general rule for this sort of scenario is $10^n$ combinations, where $n$ is the number of digits.

Comment: Easy Answer when you think about it.. I was wondering now, how many 8 characture combinations are possible using the digits 0 through 9 and also using the 26 letter alphabite where Upper and lower case can be used? Would it be 8^62 given 26 Upper Case and 26 Lower case plus 10 Digits which equal 62, or does it get alittle more complicated when you add the alphabit it to the question???

Comment: That's a different question. Now you have $2\times26+10=62$ choices each time (counting differences between upper/lower case but not including special characters. Now it's $62^n$, i.e., $62^8$. What makes it even more interesting if you have restrictions on repeating characters.

Comment: @Daniel, if you like the answer, you could accept it by clicking the checkmark. You could also append the question to addthe more complex one, and I could append the answer accordingly. :D